# Random voronoi diagrams in $2D$. How can I calculate expected sets of $\epsilon$ neighborhoods as function of metric?

Tags: probability, soft-question, voronoi-diagram

I just built my own OpenGL Voronoi diagram calculator.

After having looked at a few randomly generated images, I grew curious if it is possible to prove or disprove that some particular choice of metric will give more frequently occuring $\epsilon$ neighborhoods where $4$ different areas are present.

In other words, given $N$ points $p_k$ uniformly placed on $[0,1]^2$ splitting the plane into different areas so that each point $p$ is assigned color $c_k$ for $k$ for which $\min_k \|p-p_k\|$, how can I find the expected number of $\epsilon$ neighborhoods which have 4 different $k$ within it.

How will this number be different for different choices of metrics and of $N$?

With $\epsilon$-neighborhood around a point $p$, I mean a set defined by $$\forall q : \|q-p\|\leq \epsilon$$

Here is a sample of Manhattan distance for $N = 16$

[image]

**Edit** (For some reason I cannot write comments on this machine or browser.)

The reason why I am interested in intersections of precisely 4 different areas (and not 3 or 5) is the 4 color theorem which I read about as a child and which I also read was proven with help of using computers.

Comment: I am familiar with Voronoi diagrams but don't know what an $\epsilon$ neighborhood is. Is it the dilated set with radius $\epsilon$ ? If such is the case, why not considering plainly the case $\epsilon=0$ (for example a cell having 4 neighboring cells) ?

Comment: I meant a set with "radius" $\epsilon$ with respect to the metric and having a center point placed so that at least 1 point each belonging to 4 different areas are within.

Comment: Wait... if at least one such point exists for any combination of 4 k:s then it is very likely that an infinitude of such points exist, but we want to count every such occurrence only once if at least one exists. Hmm. I should have thought of this formulation a bit better.

Comment: So your $\epsilon$ neighborhoods are plainly **balls** with radius $\epsilon$ for the given metric.

Comment: Could you explain why you are interested to have $4$ (and not $3$, or $5$...) different areas covered by your balls ? What do you intend to "probe" with them ? Capture the density of "short boundary pieces" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie : Mostly because of the 4 color theorem.